# Is there a spell checker in vespa

Tags: spell-checking, vespa

Is there a spell checker in vespa. I want to show suggestions, if the user enters a wrong keyword. A few google searches hinted at query rewriters. How can it be configured and used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in spellchecker in Vespa. There is a query rewriting feature described here https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/query-rewriting.html but it's based on pre-defined rules.  Your best option is to integrate with a spellchecker like http://hunspell.github.io/ in a custom searcher, see https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/searcher-development.html.

Comment: When searching for spell checker, I bumped into a class https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/blob/master/container-search/src/main/java/com/yahoo/search/query/rewrite/rewriters/MisspellRewriter.java. Any idea about the purpose of this class?

Comment: Hi! Yes, this searcher has a dependency on an internal service which is not in the public domain which does linguistic analysis of the input query and provides spelling correction and other query annotations.